Series Solution to the associated Legendre equation
I'm attempting to solve the associate Legendre equation using the method of Frobenius (series solution) to obtain the conditions on $l, m$ of the spherical harmonics.  I haven't found an explicit description of the approach anywhere online, and my approach doesn't seem to be working.  I arrive at $l=0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$ , but I don't know how to interpret the constraint on $m$.  I'd appreciate an additional set of eyes on this, if someone has the time.
Start with the associated Legendre equation in spherical coordinates:
$$
\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin(\theta) \frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial\theta}\right)+[l(l+1)\sin^2(\theta)-m^2]\Theta=0
$$
Introduce the substitution $x=\cos(\theta)  \Rightarrow  \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}=-\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
$$
\sin^2(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\sin^2(\theta) \frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x}\right)+[l(l+1)\sin^2(\theta)-m^2]\Theta=0
$$
Now substitute $\sin^2(\theta)=(1-x^2)$
$$
(1-x^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left((1-x^2) \frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x}\right)+[l(l+1)(1-x^2)-m^2]\Theta=0
$$
Expand the differentiation
$$
(1-x^2) \left[-2x\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x}+(1-x^2) \frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial x^2}\right]+[l(l+1)(1-x^2)-m^2]\Theta=0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial x^2}(1-2x^2+x^4)-\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x}(2x-2x^3)+[l(l+1)(1-x^2)-m^2]\Theta=0
$$
This is where we'll start the series solution.  Assume $\Theta=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{ a_{j}x^{j}}$.  Then $\frac{\partial\Theta}{\partial x}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{ j a_{j}x^{j-1}}$ and $\frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial x^2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{ j(j-1) a_{j}x^{j-2}}$.
Plugging this in, we get
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\bullet}j(j-1)a_{j}(x^{j-2}-2x^{j}+x^{j+2})-\sum_{j=0}^{\bullet\bullet}ja_{j}(2x^{j}-2x^{j+2})+\sum_{j=0}^{\bullet\bullet\bullet}[l(l+1)a_{j}(x^{j}-x^{j+2})-m^{2}a_{j}x^{j}]=0
$$
First focus on the first sum, labeled $\bullet$.  Let $j'\equiv j-2$ in the first and second terms of this sum
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\bullet}\dots=\sum_{j'=-2}^{'}((j'+2)(j'+1)a_{j'+2}x^{j'})-\sum_{j'=-2}^{''}(2(j'+2)(j'+1)a_{j'+2}x^{j'+2})+\sum_{j=0}^{'''}(j(j-1)a_{j}x^{j+2})
$$
Reindex the $'$ and $''$ sums so that $j' \rightarrow j$.  Recognize that the first two terms are zero, so we can start those sums from $j=0$.
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\bullet}\dots=\sum_{j=0}((j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}x^{j})-(2(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}x^{j+2})+(j(j-1)a_{j}x^{j+2})
$$
Now bring back the $\bullet\bullet$ and $\bullet\bullet\bullet$ sums.  Group by powers of $x^j$
$$
\sum_{j=0}\{x^{j}[(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}-2ja_{j}+l(l+1)a_{j}-m^{2}a_{j}]\\+x^{j+2}[-2(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}+j(j-1)a_{j}+2ja_{j}-l(l+1)a_{j}]\}=0
$$
Now, address the coefficients of $x^{j+2}$.  For this sum to produce zero, those coefficients must be zero, leading to the recursion relation
$$
a_{j+2}=a_{j}\frac{j(j-1)+2j-l(l+1)}{2(j+2)(j+1)}
$$
For the function to be square-integrable, this series must truncate, and so the numerator must produce zero for some value of j.
$$
j(j-1)+2j-l(l+1)=0 \Rightarrow l(l+1)=j(j+1)
$$
The solutions are $l=j$ and $l=-(j+1)$.  The latter solution is not applicable, since negative values of $l$ are unphysical (interpretation??).  Hence, $l=0, +1, +2, +3, \dots$.
Now to the other term in the final sum. Plug in $j \rightarrow l$.  Set the coefficients of $x^l=0$.
$$
a_{l+2}=a_{l}\frac{2l-l(l+1)+m^{2}}{(l+2)(l+1)}
$$
Again, the series must truncate, so $2l-l(l+1)+m^{2}=0\Rightarrow m^{2}=l(l-1)$
What does this mean?
If $l=0$, then $m=0$
If $l=1$, then $m=0$
If $l=2$, then $m=\sqrt{2}$ ???
The condition on the azimuthal portion of the wavefunction restrains $m$ to be an integer.  I think I must have screwed up somewhere.
I thought maybe I need to consider the other solution $j=-(l+1)$.  If I do that, the recursion relation looks like
$$
a_{-l+1}=a_{-l-1}\frac{2(-l-1)-l(l+1)+m^{2}}{(-l+1)(-l)}
$$
The truncation condition is $m^{2}=l^{2}+l+2l+2=(l+1)(l+2)$.  I'm not sure how to interpret this.  Also, the indices on the $a$ coefficients are garbage.
Did I make a mistake somewhere?  I'm not even sure what the condition on $m$ should look like to produce the condition $m\le l$.  I appreciate anyone willing to take the time to slog through this.  Thank you.

There are a couple of things going wrong here, but the main one is the following: the associated Legendre functions for $n\neq0$ are not generally polynomials, so if you're doing things this way, you don't want to truncate the infinite series by finding where the recursion relation gives you zero.

@march.  I think a glaring error in this approach is that I assume that the coefficients of $x^{j+2}$ must vanish independently of those of $x^j$.  With that in mind, I tried writing the sums all with the same power of $x$, and then peeling off the first couple terms in a few of the sums, so that I had $a_2$ in terms of $a_0$, $a_3$ in terms of $a_1$, and an expression that related $a_{n+2}$ to $a_n$.  This wasn't enlightening either.

@march.  I think I understand why the series solution won't work.  Please entertain this idea.  If $x=cos(\theta)$, then $x$ can only take on values from -1 to 1.  Under this restriction, the series doesn't grow without bound.  It's not necessary that the coefficients go to zero.  In fact, the coefficients don't even need to approach zero, I think.  They just need to not grow too quickly.

I'll write an answer later today. I had to go through the process myself to see where things went wrong (and yes, I'd noticed that you were independently setting those coefficients to zero when they should be combined).

What you've said seems reasonable.  And you can be even more specific about it. See the end of my answer.

In the OP, there are two things that are going wrong.  The first is that there's no reason why you should be separately setting the $a_j$ and $a_{j+2}$ coefficients to zero.  It's important to remember that we are using an important theorem about analytic functions, that
$$
0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\implies \forall n\,,a_n = 0\,,
$$
provided that there is a finite radius of convergence for the sum on the left (in which, of course, the function is zero).  Thus, if have something of the form
$$
0= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^{n+2}\,,
$$
there's nothing we can conclude about the coefficients $a_n$ and $c_n$ \emph{separately}. Instead, we have to (carefully) reindex the sums so that we get one sum that's equal to zero.
The second issue is that for $m$ odd, the associated Legendre "polynomials" $P_l^m(x)$ are not polynomials at all. (I do not know why they are called associated Legendre polynomials instead of associated Legendre functions; it is an unfortunate terminology.)
To do this right, we should first assume that the function can be expanded in the form $x^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ and find the indicial equation to solve for $r$. I won't go through that, and I'll just assume that $r=0$ (and those \emph{are} the functions we're looking for). Instead, we assume that $\Theta(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j$, and plug it into the differential equation. The result is
\begin{align*}
0
&=
\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } l (l+1) a_j x^{j+2}
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-2 j) a_j x^{j+2}
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-j(j-1)) a_j x^{j+2}
\\&\quad\mbox{}
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-l (l+1)) a_j x^j
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } m^2 a_j x^j
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } 2 j a_j x^j
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } 2 j(j-1) a_j x^j
\\&\quad\mbox{}
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-j(j-1)) a_j x^{j-2}\,.
\end{align*}
Now, we need to align all the sums so that they have the same explicit power of $x$. For reasons that will be clear later, we choose to reindex the sums so that they all have power $x^{j-2}$. Thus, if the explicit power is $x^{j+2}$, we have to reindex as $j'=j-4$, and if the explicit power is $x^j$, we have to reindex as $j'=j-2$. The result is then
\begin{align*}
0
&=
\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-(j-1) j) a_j x^{j-2}
\\&\quad\mbox{}
+\sum _{j=2}^{\infty } (-l (l+1) a_{j-2}) x^{j-2}
+\sum _{j=2}^{\infty } m^2 a_{j-2} x^{j-2}
+\sum _{j=2}^{\infty } 2 (j-2) a_{j-2} x^{j-2}
 +\sum _{j=2}^{\infty } 2 (j-3) (j-2) a_{j-2} x^{j-2}
\\&\quad\mbox{}
+\sum _{j=4}^{\infty } l (l+1) a_{j-4} x^{j-2}
+\sum _{j=4}^{\infty } (-(j-5) (j-4)) a_{j-4}x^{j-2}
+\sum _{j=4}^{\infty } (-2 (j-4)) a_{j-4} x^{j-2}\,,
\end{align*}
and we can combine the sums together at this point as
\begin{align*}
0&= \sum _{j=2}^{\infty } a_{j-2} x^{j-2} \left(2 j^2-8 j-l (l+1)+m^2+8\right)
\\&\quad\mbox{}
+\sum _{j=4}^{\infty } a_{j-4} \left(-j^2+7 j+l (l+1)-12\right) x^{j-2}
\\&\quad\mbox{}
+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-(j-1) j) a_j x^{j-2}\,.
\end{align*}
Finally, we note the following. In the third sum, the first two ($j=0$ and $j=1$) terms are zero due to the $j(j-1)$ in the coefficient. In the second sum, we can extend the sum from $j=4$ down to starting at $j=2$ provided we explicitly state that $a_{-2}=a_{-1}=0$. Thus, all of these sums start at the same index ($j=2)$, and they all have the same power of $x$, namely $x^{j-2}$, and hence we can set the overall coefficient to zero.  We can then solve for $a_j$, and the result is
\begin{align*}
a_j = \frac{\left(2 (j-2)^2-l (l+1)+m^2\right)}{j(j-1)}a_{j-2}-\frac{\left(j^2-7 j-l (l+1)+12\right)}{j(j-1)}a_{j-4}\,.
\end{align*}
This relation, defined for $j>1$, along with the conditions $a_{-2}=a_{-1}=0$, defines our two-term recurrence relation to get $P_l^m(x)$. Note that $a_0$ and $a_1$ are free parameters and that the recurrence relation relates $a_j$ to $a_{j-2}$ and $a_{j-4}$, and so the resulting function is always the sum of an even function (proportional to $a_0$) and an odd function (proportional to $a_1$).

To check this, we can set $m=0$ and see if we get the Legendre polynomials. I won't work out the details, but it does work. Using the recurrence relation to reconstruct the functions for $l=0$, $l=1$, and $l=2$, we get
\begin{align*}
\Theta_{l=0}^{m=0}(x) &=
a_0 + a_1 \left(x+ \frac{x^3}{3} +  \frac{x^5}{5}+\cdots\right)
=a_0P_0(x) +a_1 Q_0(x)
\\
\Theta_{l=1}^{m=0}(x) &=
a_0 \left(1-x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\cdots\right)+a_1 x
=a_0 Q_1(x) + a_1 P_1(x)
\\
\Theta_{l=2}^{m=0}(x) &=
a_0 \left(1-3 x^2\right)+a_1 \left(x-\frac{2 x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{5}+\cdots\right)
=a_0 P_2(x) + a_1 Q_2(x)
\,,
\end{align*}
where $P_l(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial, and $Q_l(x)$ is the Legendre function of the second kind (that doesn't behave nicely at $x=\pm1$). (Note that we have defined the $P$'s and $Q$'s with different normalizations, but that doesn't matter.)

For $m=1$, you can check that neither of the two functions (one proportional to $a_0$ and the other proportional to $a_1$) are polynomials. But you can also check that one of the two functions always behaves nicely at $x=\pm1$ and that the other always blows up real good at $x=\pm1$. This allows us to choose the one that behaves nicely and call that our associated Legendre "polynomial". This is true for every odd $m$.  For every even $m$, you can check that one of the two functions is a polynomial, and so that's the function that behaves nicely, and that's our associated Legendre function.

Finally, here's one of the standard ways the associated Legendre "polynomials" are defined.  By clever investigation of the differential equation, we decide to make one last transformation: define $\Theta(x) = (1-x^2)^{m/2} y(x)$. The differential equation becomes
$$
\left(-l(l+1)+m^2+m\right) p(x)+2 (m+1) x p'(x)+\left(x^2-1\right) p''(x)=0\,.
$$
If we solve this via a power series solution, we arrive at a recurrence relation
$$
a_j=\frac{ (j-l+m-2) (j+l+m-1)}{(j-1) j}a_{j-2}\,.
$$
It is possible to show that no matter what we choose for $l$ and $m$---provided that they satisfy the standard conditions that they are both intergers, $l\geq0$, and $-l\leq m \leq l$---we always get a polynomial for one of the two solutions. Thus, the associated Legendre functions are of the form
$$
P_l^m(x) =  (1-x^2)^{m/2} y(x)\,,
$$
where $y(x)$ is a polynomial. (In fact, $y$ is some number of derivatives of one of the Legendre polynomials.)
